# Unintended(unexpected) change in matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, ram, file-handling

I am trying to do the shortest path finding program with Dijkstra algorithm for a school project.

I must use two different files one contains cities and their code numbers, for example,

New York-1, Chicago-2 etc.

The other one contains distance between two cities, for example,

New York-Chicago-789.

I kept city names in a char matrix and never change it but at the end of the program when I printed all, the matrix has some different characters and this causes two missing distance in neighborhood matrix. I printed matrix at different places in the program to understand where it is corrupted. I think it corrupts when I call addDistance function.

PS: I declared city name matrix in another function and assign it to **matrix variable in this function.

```
    void addToNM (){
        char ch;
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("sehir mesafe.txt","r");

        int (*neighborhoodMatrix)[counter] = calloc(counter,sizeof (*neighborhoodMatrix)); /// Allocating memory to neighborhood matrix.
        char (*city) [15] = calloc(15,sizeof(*city)); /// Allocating memory to city matrix.
        char number[3];

        int z = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

        char **matrix = addToCCM();

        while((ch=fgetc(fp))!= EOF)
        {
            if (ch == '-')
            {
                if(x==1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    x++;
                }
                y = 0;
                continue;
            }
            else if (ch>=48 && ch<=57)
            {
                number[z]=ch; /// adding numbers to number array.
                z++;
                continue;
            }
            else if (ch == '\n')
            {
                addDistance(compare0(city,matrix,counter),compare1(city,matrix,counter),neighborhoodMatrix,atoi(number)); // I think corruption happens here. !!!
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<15; j++)
                    {
                    city[i][j] = '\0';
                    }
                }
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                    number[i]= '\0';
                }
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
                z = 0;
                continue;
            }
            else{
                city[x][y] = ch;
                y++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
}
```

Functions in that line.

```
int compare0 (char cm[][15],char ccm[][15],int counter){ /// finds the city number for city 1 and returns it.
    for(int i=1; i<counter; i++){
        if(!strcmp(cm[0],ccm[i])){ /// compares two strings given. ccm stands for cityCodeMatrix. cm stands for city
            return i;
        }
    }
}

    int compare1 (char cm[][15],char ccm[][15],int counter){ /// finds the city number for city 2 and returns it.
        for(int i=1; i<counter; i++){
            if(!strcmp(cm[1],ccm[i])){ /// compares two strings given. ccm stands for cityCodeMatrix. cm stands for city.
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    void addDistance (int i, int j, int nm[][counter], int distance){ /// adds distance to neighborhood matrix. nm stands for neighborhood matrix.
        nm[i][j] = distance;
        nm[j][i] = distance;
    }
```

[image: City matrix freshly assigned]

[image: City matrix after calling addDistance function]

Comment: You need to show us a [MCVE] here.

Comment: I added the screenshots of printed city code matrix. When it's freshly assigned and after calling addDistance function.

Comment: Hmmm, 1) What happens if `int compare0 (char cm[][15],char ccm[][15],int counter)` does not find any match?  There is no return.  Is this possible?  2) Better to use `int ch` with `while((ch=fgetc(fp))!= EOF)`  3) More understandable to use `else if (ch>='0' && ch<='9')` than `else if (ch>=48 && ch<=57)`

Comment: `char number[3];` is insufficient to store `"789"` as a string.

Comment: The 15 in `calloc(15,sizeof(*city))` is suspicious, I'd expect `calloc(NUM_OF_CITIES,sizeof(*city))` when `NUM_OF_CITIES` is something like 23 or more.  `x++` can occur past `NUM_OF_CITIES` without detection - it lacks a range check.

Comment: I am not holding all the cities in 'city'. I am holding them in another matrix which represented in this function as 'matrix'. 'city' holds two city names at a time. And re-assigning every time while pointer passing to another line.

Comment: In theory compare0 or compare1 always should find a match and return a valid number. But when ccm matrix corrupts probably they are returning a non-valid number like numOfCity+1 passing beyond matrix limits or not returning something at all. Could it be the reason of corruption?